# convert query from MySql query To mongoDB query usin php driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I have to convert this query from **mysql** to **mongoDB** using **php**

```
SELECT `member_id`, `social_network_id`, `content_type_id` from recent_activity where  content_type_id  = 10  AND social_network_id = 9 group by member_id  order by  recent_activity_id  desc limit 5
```

I need the result like :

```
array(2) {
        ["content_id"]=>
        string(6) "122558"
        ["member_id"]=>
        string(6) "180306",
        ["content_type_id"]=>
        string(6) "10",
        ["social_network_id"]=>
        string(6) "9",
      },
      array(2) {
        ["content_id"]=>
        string(6) "122549"
        ["member_id"]=>
        string(6) "180305",
        ["content_type_id"]=>
        string(6) "10",
        ["social_network_id"]=>
        string(6) "9",
      },
      array(2) {
        ["content_id"]=>
        string(6) "122528"
        ["member_id"]=>
        string(6) "180304",
        ["content_type_id"]=>
        string(6) "10",
        ["social_network_id"]=>
        string(6) "9",
      },
```

I tried  Aggregation Framework as

```
 $result = $collection->aggregate(array(
            '$match' => array('content_type_id'=>"10", "social_network_id"=>"9"),
            '$project' => array('content_type_id'=>1, "social_network_id"=>1, "content_id"=>1),
            '$group' => array('_id' => array('member_id'=>'$member_id')),
            '$sort'  => array('_id'=>-1),
            '$limit' => 5,
        ));
```

But i got this error

```
["errmsg"]=>
  string(80) "exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field."
```

and I tried

```
$result = $collection->aggregate(array(
                    '$match' => array('content_type_id'=>"10", "social_network_id"=>"9"),
                    '$project' => array("_id"=>'$content_id' ,'content_type_id'=>1),
                    '$group' => array('_id' => array('content_id'=>'$content_id', 'member_id'=>'$member_id')), 
                )
            );
```

And I tried this:

```
$array = array(
                array('$match' => array('content_type_id'=>"10", "social_network_id"=>"9")),
                array(
                    '$group' => array(
                        "_id" => array("member_id" => '$member_id'),
                    ),
                ),
                array('$limit'=>20),
                array('$sort'=>array('_id'=>-1)),
            );
        $results = $collection->aggregate($array);
```

But the result does not mach my expectation , the grouping working well but its return only member_id with other fields as

```
array(2) {
  ["result"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["_id"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["member_id"]=>
        string(5) "18036"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["_id"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["member_id"]=>
        string(6) "180306"
      }
    }
  }
  ["ok"]=>
  float(1)
}
```

and to return other fields

So I need to get latest 5 activty for member grouped by by member so the result should be 5 member with 5 activity with diferent member ids and list all data fro each member

My collection Data like :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528e0b3d33df1b21228dc6a0"), "content_id" : "122542", "content_type_id" : "10", "date_added" : ISODate("2013-11-10T14:06:17Z"), "member_id" : "180306", "platform_id" : "2", "social_network_id" : "91" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5291a7a733df1bc3048b4567"), "content_id" : "122542", "content_type_id" : "10", "date_added" : ISODate("2013-11-10T14:06:17Z"), "member_id" : "180326", "platform_id" : "2", "social_network_id" : "9" }


{ "_id" : ObjectId("5291a7a733df1bc3048b4567"), "content_id" : "220252", "content_type_id" : "10", "date_added" : ISODate("2013-11-10T14:06:17Z"), "member_id" : "180316", "platform_id" : "2", "social_network_id" : "9" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5291a7a733df1bc3048b4567"), "content_id" : "110252", "content_type_id" : "10", "date_added" : ISODate("2013-11-10T14:06:17Z"), "member_id" : "180316", "platform_id" : "2", "social_network_id" : "9" }
```

I'm new to mongoDB AND I spent a lot of time to convert this query and to solve this error , any one can help me

Thanks

Comment: Your SQL statement is not legal SQL syntax - you cannot select multiple columns but only include some of them in your group by plus order by goes after the group by.  Maybe you can explain in plain English what you are trying to do?   Your listed output isn't clear - content_id is different but the other fields are the same - why is member_id the same - do you want to group by it as well?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, I edit my question , I  need to get latest 5 activty for member grouped by by member so the result should be 5 member with 5 activity with different member ids and list all data fro each member

Comment: @AsyaKamsky It's perfectly legal with Fisher Price My First SQL Server. Or, MySQL, as its sometimes known. Without any aggregate function it's basically `SELECT DISTINCT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 5`

Comment: But how I can do that using php mongodb driver

Comment: I'm no MongoDB expert (I do know that it's web-scale, however), but you don't need to aggregate anything in MySQL ... so you probably don't need to aggregate anything in MongoDB. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/

Comment: @ta.speot.is m yes but we cant use limit and sort with distinct , https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2130

Comment: If you want five most recent events for five different members then it cannot be done in aggregation framework. If you want all activity for five members most recently active then that can be done, but I can't tell which you want. You say five members - how should those be chosen?

Comment: I need the five last activities for distinct member.

Comment: What does the collection data look like?

Comment: @RyanSchumacher , I edit my question see it please I added my collection data

Answer (score 2):

Solution to

> exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.

```
$result = $collection->aggregate(array(
    array('$match' => array('content_type_id'=>"10", "social_network_id"=>"9")),
    array('$project' => array("_id"=>'$content_id' ,'content_type_id'=>1)),
    array('$group' => array('_id' => array('content_id'=>'$content_id', 'member_id'=>'$member_id')))
));
```

*Note the array wrapping each pipeline*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its not working for me , it was return an empty set like 
array(2) {
  ["result"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["_id"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  ["ok"]=>
  float(1)
}

Answer (score 1):

The correct query is:

```
$array = array(
            array('$match' => array('content_type_id'=>"10", "social_network_id"=>"9")),
            array('$project' => array( 'member_id'=>1, 'social_network_id'=>1, 'content_type_id'=>1)),
            array('$group' => array("_id" => array("member_id" => '$member_id', 'social_network_id'=>'$social_network_id', 'content_type_id'=>'$content_type_id'))),
            array('$limit'=>20),
            array('$sort'=>array('recent_activity_id'=>-1)),
        );
$results = $collection->aggregate($array);
```

Use:

- `$match` to filter the initial set to aggregate
- `$project` to reshape the
  resulting document: add new fields or include fields from the
  original document
- `$group` to group by, don't forget to include all the fields you want to select.

---

*note about your schema design:*

consider changing your schema to avoid the group by (which can be slow on production)

you can use a structure like this:

```
{ 
  member_id: 1, 
  shared_contents: [ { social_network_id: 'fb', content_type_id: 1234 }, { ... } ],
  recent_activity_id: 12345
}
```

as you can see you can have arrays of sub-documents in your documents, in this way you have the data ready to be fetched. (be sure this doesn't interfere with the other use-cases of your application)

---

**Update**:
to return also all the ids of the aggregated items, add [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) to the $group and $project:

```
array('$project' => array( 'member_id'=>1, 'social_network_id'=>1, 'content_type_id'=>1, 'content_id'=>1)),
```

and:

```
array('$group' => array("_id" => array("member_id" => '$member_id', content_ids: { $addToSet: "$content_id" }, 'social_network_id'=>'$social_network_id', 'content_type_id'=>'$content_type_id'))),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but I need to return "content_id", if I include the ""content_id" inside the $group and $project,  then the group by does not working,  I include it like  array('$project' => array( 'member_id'=>1, 'social_network_id'=>1, 'content_type_id'=>1, 'content_id'=>1)),
            array('$group' => array("_id" => array("member_id" => '$member_id', 'social_network_id'=>'$social_network_id', 'content_type_id'=>'$content_type_id','content_id'=>'$content_id'))),

Comment: Sorry, but there is a logical flaw in your request: you are trying do aggregate MULTIPLE documents, and so you will have multiple content_id, not only one. This is why if you specify the content_id in the group the aggregation doesn't work. (try it with your original query on Mysql, there will be the same problem)

Comment: I've added a solution, however this is no longer the original query

Answer (score 0):

You have records which contain `member_id` and `recent_activity_id` and you want to return the five most recent activities for each member (for a particular social network and content type).

This cannot currently be done entirely in MongoDB.  You need [this feature](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377) to be available and it has not yet been implemented.  The closest you can get is you can return all recent activities for each member and then limit the array to first five members on the client side.

Here is how you would do it for all recent activities:

```
db.recent_activity.aggregate( [
    { $match : { content_type_id:10, social_network_id:9} },
    { $sort  : { recent_activity_id:-1} },
    { $group : { _id : { member_id:"$member_id", 
                         content_type_id:"$content_type_id", 
                         social_network_id:"$social_network_id" 
                 },
                 activity : { $push : "$recent_activity_id" }
               }
    }
] );
```

If the [$slice operator is implemented in aggregation framework](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074), that would be another way you could limit the activity array to latest five but that's also not available in the current version.